# IF in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on stored procedure and i face a problem i'm not able to resolve, even with research ...

I'd like to give the possibility for my user to fill a name (NOM) on some records, but they are not forced to. if they dont, i'd like to fill if myself with a date, and that's my trouble ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[G_INSERT](
    @NOM Text = null
) AS
BEGIN 
    IF (@NOM IS NULL OR @NOM = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @NOM = 'Evaluation du' + CONVERT(text, GETDATE(), 100)
    END

    INSERT INTO toto(
        NOM)
    VALUES (
        @NOM
    )
END
```

This is my current procedure, but it isnt working ... Visual studio doesnt report any error, but when i click on "update", the update fails :(

It might be the "if begin ...end", because when i delete it, it works fine.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:

The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
in line 27 (the "if" line, NOM is a varchar(300) in the DB)

Comment: Edit your question and explain how the update fails.

Comment: I edited it, but it bugged me out even more ... NOM is a varchar(300)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

`TEXT` is an outdated data type that you should no longer use (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)).

You can write the stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[G_INSERT] (
    @NOM VARCHAR(255) = null
) AS
BEGIN 
    IF (@NOM IS NULL OR @NOM = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @NOM = 'Evaluation du' + CONVERT(text, GETDATE(), 100)
    END

    INSERT INTO toto(NOM)
        SELECT (CASE WHEN @NOM IS NULL OR @NOM = ''
                     THEN 'Evaluation du ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), GETDATE(), 100)
                     ELSE @NOM
                END);
END;
```

You can simplify the logic and remove the `IF`.

Comment: I always thought that TEXT was bad for performance, but easier to use, than varchar ^^ 
BTW, i wasnt using TEXT, i just wrote too fast my procedure :/
Still thank you (and i simplify the procedure to show you, it's like 20times bigger, so i rather use a single little IF than a big select in the middle of the insert into ^^, still thank you for showing me something i didnt know: the select case)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out that `@NOM` is text, according to the procedure. Simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[G_INSERT] (
    @NOM VARCHAR(255) = null
) AS
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO toto(NOM)
        SELECT iif( @NOM IS NULL OR @NOM = '','Evaluation du ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), GETDATE(), 100),@NOM);
END;
```